# Google OAuth With NextAuth for receiving google reviews on NextJs 13.3.0

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

I've got a issue when I tried to develop a section with google reviews for my client with Api Places (new).

the code here:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const options = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    })
    // Puedes añadir más proveedores aquí
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token:any, user:any, account:any) {
      if (account) {
        // token.id = user.id;
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session(session:any, token:any) {
      // session.user.id = token.id;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    
      return session;
    },
  },
}

const authHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, options:any) => NextAuth(req, res, options)
export default authHandler
```

I'd like just get customers reviews with Api Places (new) using NextAuth.

The code provided up, it's localed on app/api/auth/[nextauth].ts and everything it's working correctly but after the user press login on the button and google redirect to login with google, after accept is the access permision from app to access to the information of the google account of the user, this redirects to a page where nextjs show me an error and say
" Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server. " but I don't know where this error is ocurred. The url where show me this error is this. " http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google?code=4/0AfJohXkgdbANBUEJmqkYIK4dSzAJF75am3AeVojgTpScKo7wdv1OjI8cY9cJaqmUn8yKqA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform ".

I know that I need pass this code to server to get a jwt token, but where I could do this?.

I've tried to read the nextauth documentation to figureout a solution but doesn't show me something like that, also I've watch some videos where nextauth works correctly. I expected this call show me the jwt token to do the another call and get google reviews.

Comment: Is it stated in the documentation of NextAuth that it supports such implementation with oAuth?